# Adding an image on the right end of the navigation bar in navbarPage() layout in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to replicate a similar layout as RStudio's SuperZip Shiny dashboard available here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html

The code for that app is available here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example

Based off that code, I would like to add an image on the right end of the navigation bar (let's say the [Rstudio logo](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gray-125.png)), highlighted with the red box in the image below. I assume I'd need to add some HTML and CSS code but I'm unsure on how to proceed.

[image]

EDIT: My question is marked as duplicate. Note that the question that it's being referred to is to place the image on the LEFT END of the title bar. I'm looking to place it on the RIGHT END of the title bar.